# Connecting to a mysql Database via PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok, Ive been playing around with PHP and databases. Note, Im doing all my work on a webserver hosted by bluehost. 
So I went into the cpanel and set up a database called gagalugc_stocks.
I also setup a username (test) and a password (password) and added them to be able to control the databse. Below is my script in an attempt to connect to it, not it is also on the server.

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','test','password');
if(!$connect){die('Could not reach database!');}
mysql_select_db("gagalugc_stocks", $connect)
?>
```

-Thanks

NOTE: The problem is that it can never reach the database.

Comment: You probably have a wrong host. Double check it.

Comment: 2 things - you might specify 3306 as the port, and the bluehost documentation has the username and database name having this format: username_databasename.  If gagalugc isn't your username, that might be the reason.

Comment: @JonathanBarlow gagalugc is my username. How would I specify 3306 as the port though?

Comment: @DenisErmolin It cant connect to the database =/

Comment: Are you sure about the `localhost` part? This should be different unless the server **itself** is your own computer.

Comment: @inhan What you say is not true. PHP is executed server-side, so the database server must be local (or accessible) to the server, not the client. `localhost` actually makes sense here.

Comment: @Dragan Marjanovic Since you said you made your db settings in the cpanel, localhost should be fine.

Comment: @SoboLAN I thought localhost would be fine to as it is on the server but I tried changing it to the server hostname (box794.bluehost.com:port) and it worked.

Comment: I'm not quite sure about this, but isn't a database connection over the internet non-sense?

Comment: Let's say you have an user submitting a form which should be written to the database. He'll click on submit, data is being sent over the internet to your webserver, which then sends the data over the internet to your database, instead of taking the faster local route. If you use localhost (or the local hostname), php won't have to send the data over the internet. I'd ask your hoster if your db runs on another machine as the webserver, and if so, ask for the local hostname / ip.

Comment: oh I see Ill try adding the port to localhost ;)

Comment: @Ahatius Turn out localhost works aswell just need to make sure to have the port on.

Comment: Dragan, it is always helpful to look at PHP's documentation online.  You can see that the mysql_connect function has a lot of parameters that you aren't using, such as the port:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php  The port isn't really a parameter, but they give an example of how to append the port to the hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't check for port when adding database make sure to specify host and port

```
(localhost:2083)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'test', 'password')
or die ('<b>Could not connect: </b>' . mysql_error());
$result = mysql_select_db("gagalugc_stocks")
or die ('<b>Could not connect: </b>' . mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: In which way is this technically different from what the OP posted?

Comment: @Ahatius I agree with you but.. on the other hand, this code prints the error message if/when the connection fails.

Comment: this code will add a mysql error string. your static error msg is not enough to debug. it could be a network error or even a authentication error.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost:2083','test','password');
if(!$connect){die('Could not reach database!');}
mysql_select_db("gagalugc_stocks", $connect)
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

For local system:-

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con){
    die('Unable to connect to the server ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

For website or remote server:-

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con){
    die('Unable to connect to the server ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("databasename", $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

for more please visit : [Algosoftwares](http://www.algosoftwares.com)